# How to create an lstdefinestyle similar to this?

Tags: listings, lstdefinestyle

I am trying to create an `lstdefinestyle` similar to the one in the image below, but for no reason the settings are not working.

[image]

**Result of my `lstdefinestyle`:**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\definecolor{constants}{RGB}{127,39,84}
\definecolor{character}{RGB}{100,169,57}

\lstdefinestyle{deltaj}{
        belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
        breaklines=true,
        columns=fullflexible,
        frame=single,
        xleftmargin=\parindent,
        language=Java,
        escapeinside={(*}{*)},
        numbers=left,
        stepnumber=1,
        numberblanklines=false,
        basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
        keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},
        commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},
        identifierstyle=\color{blue},
        stringstyle=\color{orange},
        literate=
         {\{}{{{\color{character}{\{}}}}{1}
         {\}}{{{\color{character}{\}}}}}{1}
         {SPL }{{{\color{constants}{SPL }}}}{1}
         {Features }{{{\color{constants}{Features }}}}{1}
         {Deltas }{{{\color{constants}{Deltas }}}}{1}
         {Constraints }{{{\color{constants}{Constraints }}}}{1}
         {Partitions }{{{\color{constants}{Partitions }}}}{1}
         {Products }{{{\color{constants}{Products }}}}{1}
         {when }{{{\color{constants}{when }}}}{1}
         {\& }{{{\color{constants}{\& }}}}{1}
         {| }{{{\color{constants}{| }}}}{1}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=deltaj]
SPL ReminderPL {
   Features = {Reminder, GUI, ManageReminder}

   Deltas = {dBase}

   Constraints {
      Reminder & GUI & ManageReminder;
   }

   Partitions {
      {dBase} when (Reminder & GUI & ManageReminder);
   }

   Products {
      Example = {Reminder, ManageReminder, GUI};
   }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code a compilable document that reproduces the result shown in your second image

Comment: @siracusa done :)

Comment: Next time plase provide a *complete* document, from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`, not just several fragments of code. Beside the two points mentioned in my answer, what changes would you still like to be applied? The differently colored identifiers before the `when` keyword can probably only be achieved by adding extra tags to your code listing. Would that be an option?

Comment: @siracusa In this case, the name of the SPL declaration (ReminderPL) is in blue, but the correct one is black. In addition, all `{` `}` are green and not just the blocks assigned to Partitions. Another problem is that in Partitions, the delta  names (dBase) do not turn green in the other image.

Also, I wanted to know what the font style is, because the font style I set up is not the same as the one I wanted.

Comment: The font looks identically to your first image for me. You didn't show a full example, so I don't know why it appears so pale in your second image. But my question still stands: Are extra markup tags in your listings okay to get the desired output? `listings`' standard features are very limited, perhaps using [`minted`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted) with defining your own pygments lexer is an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

As too long for a comment: The use of the `literate` option isn't recommended to highlight keywords or certain identifiers. `listings` provides extra options `keywords` and `keywordstyle` to define different sets of keywords and to apply a style for them, respectively. For your code the definitions might look like

```
keywords={SPL,Features,Deltas,Constraints,Partitions,Products,when},
keywordstyle=\color{constants}
```

Your left and right braces are also defined incorrectly. The commands `\{` and `\}` typeset math mode brace delimiters, which is probably not what you want in your listings. Instead use

```
literate={\{}{{{\color{character}{\char`\{}}}}{1}
         {\}}{{{\color{character}{\char`\}}}}}{1}
```